# Как влить нужные различия в файлах?

Tags: git, git-diff

Нужно прилить к существующему проекту некие отличия из репозитория на GitНub.
Запускаю команду `git diff origin/master master` и получаю безумно длинную ленту отличий.
Вопрос: как добавить изменения только к некоторым файлам?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4099805/1646082

Comment: Допишите конкретный файл через `--`

Comment: @Nofate        понял - спасибо! а можно прилить изменения в файлах только из определенных директорий?

Comment: Можно указать конкретные директории, да.

Comment: @Nofate        а как? пример команды не подскажете?

Comment: Если изменения нужны только некоторые, то нужно либо мучатся с мерджем, либо сделать по старинке. Вначале сделать git diff и сохранить себе вывод. Потом открыть в редакторе и "поправить". А потом с помощью git patch применить получившийся диф.

Comment: @KoVadim  а может заигнорить в файле .gitignore определенные файлы и директории? а потом залить к себе только нужное?

Comment: не нужно. Не придумывайте. А лучше почитайте базовые вещи по гиту. И да, забудьте все, что Вы знали о svn/cvs

Comment: @KoVadim отличная рекомендация про svn ))

Answer (score 5):

для команды *diff* можно указать «область видимости»: после всех опций и параметров перечислить произвольное количество файлов/каталогов.

чтобы «облегчить» работу программе *git* и чётко отделить опции/параметры от списка файлов/каталогов, перед списком лучше вставить спец-опцию `--`.

например:

```
$ git diff опции-и-параметры -- файл1 каталог1 каталог2/файл2 ...
```